# Get unique values from array within a range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique, indexof

I have an array, I need to return new array with the values in range (from a to b) BUT! I want to return without duplicates. I wrote the script below but it doesn't work properly.

```
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];
let newArr = [];
let funcFilter = function(arr, a, b) {
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b ) {
  if(arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1)
   newArr.push(arr[i]);
}
}
return newArr;
}
console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20))
```

Comment: does *"in range"* means sorted?

Comment: You should use `if(newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ypu need to check value in `newArr`,so `arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1` needs to be change to `newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1`

```js
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];
let newArr = [];
let funcFilter = function(arr, a, b) {
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b ) {
       if(newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
         newArr.push(arr[i]);
       }
   }
return newArr;
}
console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20))
```

Comment: yep, I did it .

Comment: this is a Good answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the values that match the criteria. Then convert into [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values and finally use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert it back into array.

```js
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];
let funcFilter = function(arr, a, b) {
    return [...new Set(arr.filter(v => v >= a && v <= b))];
}
console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` Object to get unique values and use `filter()` to filter array items;

```js
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];

let funcFilter = (arr, start, end) => Array.from(new Set(arr))
                                           .filter((v) => (v >= start && v <=end));

console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) because

> `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

```js
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];
let newArr = [];
let funcFilter = function(arr, a, b) {
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b ) {
  if(arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1)
   newArr.push(arr[i]);
}
}

return [...new Set(newArr)];
}
console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just test agains the actual index for exluding more of the same value

```
if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) === i) {
//                          ^
```

BTW, you could move the declaration of `newArr` inside of the function.

```js
var arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13],
    funcFilter = function(arr, a, b) {
        var newArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] >= a && arr[i] <= b) {
                if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) === i) { // take only the first found item
                    newArr.push(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return newArr;
    };
console.log(funcFilter(arr, 3, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [3, 9, 10, 23, 100, 100, 23, 4, 10, 13, 13];
const uniqueValue = Array.from(new Set(arr));

function getValueInTherange(array, a, b) {
  return array.filter(value => value >= a && value <= b - 1);
}

console.log(getValueInTherange(uniqueValue, 10, 50));
```

Comment: *new array with the values in range (from a to b)*